# Getting RangeError Invalid Date when trying to convert to date

Tags: javascript, string, date

I'm trying to convert a string to a date. The string is in this format: `05-FEB-2019 19:20`

But when I do the conversion it gives me RangeError: InvalidDate

```
var local_timestamp_str = "05-FEB-2019 19:20"
var local_timestamp = new Date(local_timestamp_str);
```

How can I convert such strings to date type?

UPDATE:
I'm trying to handle the above specific case as follows, where the try block converts string of "05/02/2019 20:04" format to date. That works fine. But for cases like "05-FEB-2019 19:20", it goes into the catch block giving RangeError. I want to handle this error and convert this specific format as `var local_timestamp_str = local_timestamp_str.split('-').join(' ');` and continue running the code. But it's not working and still just throws the error.

```
try {
  var local_timestamp = new Date(local_timestamp_str);

} catch (err) {
  if (err.name == 'RangeError') {

    var local_timestamp_str = local_timestamp_str.split('-').join(' ');
    var local_timestamp = new Date(local_timestamp_str);

    console.log(local_timestamp);
  } else {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Parsing of non–standard timestamps with the built–in parser is problematic and not recommended. Either write your own function (parsing DD MMM YYYY HH:mm should be no more than 4 lines of code) or use a library.

Comment: Most built–in parsers (all?) will parse  "05/02/2019 20:04" as 2 May or an invalid date, it's not equivalent to "05-FEB-2019 19:20".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the dashes may be causing your problem.

try something like this
new Date('05 February 2019 19:20 UTC');

This Mozilla page shows some valid cases.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_date

Comment: I can't change the string format. This is what I'm reading from the database.

Comment: You'll have to alter the string after you get it from the DB. Check out the link from @rtrigoso.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) The answer there should help you.

Answer (score 0):

i have update the input format.

```js
var local_timestamp_str = "05-FEB-2019 19:20".split('-').join(' ');
var local_timestamp = new Date(local_timestamp_str);
console.log(local_timestamp.toString());
```

Comment: Can there be a solution to handle conversion of two types of strings together: "02/05/2019 10:43" and "05-FEB-2019 19:20"

Comment: @user10096621—some libraries will allow that. If you want to avoid a library, write 2 simple parse functions and determine which to use based on a test, say using a regular expression.